# 'fail' and 'error' not working with SvelteKit ('cannot find name ...')

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, sveltekit

I am new to SvelteKit and learning all its best practices. I am working with forms and want to `throw error()` or `return fail()`, just like this example here [In Sveltekit, can you return 2 fail ActionResults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497660/in-sveltekit-can-you-return-2-fail-actionresults)

But I get the typescript error `cannot find name 'fail'` or `fail is not defined` when trying to run the code. It seems so fundamental but there is no mention of this anywhere in my searches.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you [importing fail](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions)? Eg `import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit'`

Comment: Hah, no! Thanks, this is yet another example of where tutorials etc skip a pretty critical part and leave newbies scratching their heads wondering where they're going wrong. Even though, it does say it here https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors#expected-errors, but you skip over it looking at the examples beneath, trying to get to building stuff as quick as possible.

Comment: No problem. The examples in Svelte's docs look like they're mostly written as diffs, so I'm guessing they expect users to start at the top and work their way down.

Comment: Can I ask what a diff is?

Comment: It's a format that compares changes in a file. The lines in the Svelte docs that are highlighted red and green, and have `+`/`-` symbols, are diffs, saying "this thing was inserted and this thing was deleted in the file." If you look at a commit on Github for example in the Unified view (rather than Split), that's the same format. (Split view has the same information, but side-by-side instead of linear).

Comment: Thanks. An extra question if I may, is it best practice to load database data in the load function of a +page/+layout.server.js file (I guess it delays the initial page load?), or allow the page to load before fetching the database data? Or is that too much back and forth, better to get it from the start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254491/discussion-between-mikeyb-and-zac-anger).

Comment: Let us not :) You're asking a bunch of unrelated questions, which isn't really how it works on StackOverflow. If you have a new question, please search to see if there's already an answer, and if not, feel free to post it as a question.